# Banco de dados Local .MDF C# Visual Studio 2017 (CONEXÃO)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, conexão

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação windows utilizando o visual studio 2017, porém me deparei com um problema, na minha máquina que estou fazendo o projeto tudo roda certinho, na outra máquina que faço os testes da erro de conexão com o banco, já instalei a versão correta do .NET e o SQL SERVER, larguei a pasta no mesmo lugar que a da outra máquina no disco C:.  Estou usando o app.config para a conexão com o banco. Acho estranho a conexão não precisar de usuário e senha do banco (ainda estou aprendendo C# e conhecendo  o visual studio).

> Obs estou programando em uma máquina com windows 10 e testando e outra
>   máquina com windows 7

App.Config

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="conn"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Sistema\Sistema.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>  
</configuration>
```

O erro é esse:

```
************** Texto de Exceção **************
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Erro ao Localizar Servidor/Instância Especificada)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   em WindowsFormsApp1.formLogin.acessar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na C:\Sisgemp\formLogin.cs:linha 44
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
   em System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
```

Comment: Você já deu permissão na pasta onde se encontra o .mdf do computador que não conecta?

Comment: Muito provável que o arquivo não exista neste endereço na outra maquina: `C:\Sistema\Sistema.mdf`

Comment: pior que existe, eu copiei a pasta do projeto do C de uma máquina para o o C da outra, conferi e o caminho esta igual

Comment: ei as permissões para a pasta, só que eu acho que é alguma coisa na minha conexão, em nenhum momento informei senha do banco nem nada. Tenho duvidas quanto a isso.